# Restoration of physical and logical volume group with data

Tags: linux, lvm

My idea was to simulate such situation on VirtualBox as: some crash happened with my hard disk drive, but I had had LVM and it was not a big deal to restore data using it.
My steps were:

> step1: initialization of disks:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb
pvcreate /dev/sdc
pvcrete /dev/sdd
```

> step2: Creation of physical volume group:

```
vgcreate vg1 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
```

> step3: Creation of a logical volume with mirror:

```
lvcreate -L 1.5G -m2 -n mir vg1
```

> step4: Creation of mount point for mir logical volume

```
sudo mkdir mnt/mir
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/vg1/mir
```

> step5: Then I add entry about mir to the /etc/fstab
>
> step6: Mounting of a mir:

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/vg1/mir /mnt/mir
```

> step7: Then I shut down my VirtualBox and deleted /dev/sdd
>
> step8: Found out which of these disks were missing

```
lvscan
```

> step9: Looked for the last archive in lvm:

```
ls -l /etc/lvm/archive/vg1*
```

> step10: Found out the missing ID:

```
less /etc/lvm/archive/vg1_00003-1776947519
```

The output was: `BgR0KJ-JClh-T2gS-k6yK-9RGn-B8Ls-LYPQP0`

> step11: I tried to restore physical volume using this command:

```
pvcreate -ff --uuid "BgR0KJ-JClh-T2gS-k6yK-9RGn-B8Ls-LYPQP0" --restorefile /etc/lvm/archive/vg1_00003-1776947519.vg /dev/sdd
```

> step12: Restoration of the group and sudden failure at the end:

```
vgcfgrestore -f /etc/lvm/archive/vg1_00003-1776947519.vg vg1
```

After pressing Enter key I got this:

`Couldn't find device with uuid kgH6Qb-0Ao3-oZ1Q-HKrz-2FWk-GLez-meCjLU
PV unknown device missing from cache
Format-specific setup for unknown device failed
Restore failed`

So another one uuid disappeared. At this point I just stuck and have not known what to do till now.
So the question is to find solution to restore physical group, logical group and data from disk which was deleted from VirtualBox. I would really appreciate for any proposes.

Answer (score 0):

Devices UUIDs change after you (re)create them, or try to replicate a server on a new machine. You can force to set a  uuid on hard disks.

```
tune2fs /dev/{device} -U {uuid}
```

Be aware is easier to do this to unmounted file systems.

Answer (score 0):

May be I am missing something, but basically I see no way to restore data in this scenario, because there is no redundancy approach set at first place. I mean something like software RAID or so.

You see, when you add these PVs in the VG, the LVM abstraction algorithm divides the data among the three. When you delete one of these, basically its data share is being completely destroyed and the data pool is corrupted and incomplete.

It is possible to restore the VG, but IMO it's not possible to restore the data in it's original state.